# Can not run Auto WEKA

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I have downloaded Auto WEKA into my computer

and installed Java Runtime Environment

and I have WIndows 10

I am trying to run the Auto WEKA by double clicking on `autoweka.jar` file after assign jar files to Java but that does not work

I also tried using creating `.bat` file same as this link suggested
yet nothing works

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-on-windows

how can I get the GUI running?